# What is "IfWinActive" counterpart for window class and process?

Tags: autohotkey

[IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) command isn't always viable as some windows don't have titles. Is there a similar command for window class (`ahk_class`) and process (`ahk_exe`)?

Comment: The parameter **WinTitle** in the [IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) command **can be the title** or partial title of the window, **and/or any other criteria described on [this page](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)**.

Comment: i.e., IfWinActive ahk_class myClass is just as good as using a title, and can also be used as IfWinActive ahk_exe myExe